# Installer only installs to root on x64 systems

Tags: visual-studio-2008, installation, 64-bit, setup-project

My MSI installer created with Visual Studio 2008 refuses to install the app in the designated directory and instead will only install the app in the root directory.  If I take the same MSI and install in on an x86 system the installer installs the app in the directory specified.

I am developing the app and MSI on Server 2008 and Win7 RC x64 (Hyper-V).  I see the same results on either development platform.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check two things:

1. Are you targeting x64 for the code?
2. Are you targeting x64 for the .MSI file?

This link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd7a85k9(VS.80).aspx explains the gotchas.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  I needed to do two things.  Set the TragetPlatform to x64 for the installer project and manually run the setup.exe using "Run as Administrator".

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue. I was able to resolve it by right-clicking and selecting "Run as Administrator"